# Debo hacer una consulta a un codigo pero en la BD esta el codigo con ceros a la izquierda

Tags: sql, oracle

Ejemplo debo consultar este codigo 2365 pero en la BD esta asi 00000002365 como puedo hacer la consulta solo escribiendo el codigo 2365 sin los ceros?

Estoy trabajando en visual studio 2015 con BD Oracle.

```
"SELECT * FROM MOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CTERCERO = '" + TBNit.Text + "'AND CTIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' AND CNUM = '" + TBCausacion.Text + "'";
```

debo quitar los ceros para TBNit.Text y TBCausacion.Text

Comment: te falta informacion amigo como el tipo de dato del campo

Comment: Tipo de datos: Entero (int)

Comment: si es entero en la db no puede estar nunca con tantos 0000 adelante...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando Oracle entonces puedes usar la función `LTRIM`, la función LTRIM de Oracle te permite definir un campo y el caracter a la izquierda que se quiere quitar, por ejemplo:

```
LTRIM(NOMBRE_COLUMNA, '0')
```

Anexo una consulta de ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA_1 T1
JOIN TABLA_2 T2
ON LTRIM(T1.CODIGO_T1, '0') = LTRIM(T2.CODIGO_T2, '0');
```

También te muestro un par de ejecuciones con sus resultados:

```
LTRIM('000123', '0')
Resultado: '123'

LTRIM('123123Tech', '123')
Resultado: 'Tech'
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: BDOM si me srive como podria hacerlo con mi consulta
    SELECT * FROM MOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CM1_TERCERO = '" + TBNit.Text + "'

Comment: Intenta colocar algo como esto: "SELECT * FROM MOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CTERCERO = LTRIM('" + TBNit.Text + "', '0')", asegúrate de usar bien las comillas y apóstrofes.

Comment: No funciona la consulta

Comment: Ya intentaste realizar la consulta desde Oracle?, pasando el valor directamente: SELECT * FROM MOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CTERCERO = LTRIM('00000002365', '0').

Comment: Pero no sirve porque no podria buscar el tercero

Comment: A que te refieres con que no podrías buscar el tercero?... Que resultado te muestra cuando realizas la consulta?

Comment: TBNit.Text  es el textbox donde yo digito la identificacion de la persona, si existe ese numero de identificacion me trae los datos de esa persona

Comment: A lo que me refería es que entres a tu base de datos (en este caso Oracle) y realices la consulta, de este modo puedes verificar si la función LTRIM te muestra los datos correctamente. Eso solo como prueba, si te devuelve los datos correctamente quiere decir que estás pasando mal los datos desde tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar el operador `LIKE` asi:

```
"SELECT * FROM TERCEROS WHERE TrTERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "%'"
```

Comment: Como lo aplico a esta consulta
    "SELECT * FROM TERCEROS WHERE TrTERCERO = '" + TBNit.Text + "'";

Comment: El campo `TrTERCERO` es donde tienes los valores o es en otro campo?

Comment: Si los valores a consultar estan en ese campo osea ka identificacion de la persona

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.